# can a website be part mysql and mysqli while I am converting

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am just starting to convert my website from mysql to mysqli and changed one of my functions to mysqli. I uploaded this new function however now no results are being displayed from the database. So is this just the code, or doesn't a whole website have to be in mysqli first before functions will work? Could it be because my database connection is still mysql?
I converted this

```
function viewOrdersAdmin(){
//This block grabs the orders
$order_list = "";
//Selecting all the orders in the table from that member
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `transactions`");

while ($transactions = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    //creating variables from the information
    $order_id = $transactions["order_id"];
    $mem_id = $transactions["mem_id"];

    $order_details = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `transactionDetails` WHERE `order_id` = $order_id GROUP BY order_id");
    $orderDetailsCount = mysql_num_rows($order_details);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($order_details)) {
        //creating variables from the information
        $order_product_id = $row["Product_ID"];

        $member_details = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `mem_id` = $mem_id");
        $memberDetailsCount = mysql_num_rows($member_details);
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($member_details)) {
            //creating variables from the information
            $order_mem_fname = $row2["mem_first_name"];
            $order_mem_lname = $row2["mem_last_name"];

        $order_list .= "Order ID:$order_id - Customer Name: $order_mem_fname $order_mem_lname  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='manage_order.php?orderid=$order_id'>View</a> &bull; <a href='manage_orders.php?deleteid=$order_id'>Delete</a><br/>";

        }
    }
}

if (count($orderDetailsCount) == 0) {
    $order_list = "You have no orders to display";
}

print_r($order_list);
}
```

To this

```
function viewOrdersAdmin(){ 
//This block grabs the orders 
$order_list = ""; 
//Selecting all the orders in the table from that member 
$sql = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM `transactions`"); 

while ($transactions = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { 
    //creating variables from the information 
    $order_id = $transactions["order_id"]; 
    $mem_id = $transactions["mem_id"]; 

    $order_details = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM `transactionDetails` WHERE `order_id` = $order_id GROUP BY order_id"); 
    $orderDetailsCount = mysqli_num_rows($order_details); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($order_details)) { 
        //creating variables from the information 
        $order_product_id = $row["Product_ID"]; 

        $member_details = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `mem_id` = $mem_id"); 
        $memberDetailsCount = mysqli_num_rows($member_details); 
        while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($member_details)) { 
            //creating variables from the information 
            $order_mem_fname = $row2["mem_first_name"]; 
            $order_mem_lname = $row2["mem_last_name"]; 

        $order_list .= "Order ID:$order_id - Customer Name: $order_mem_fname $order_mem_lname  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='manage_order.php?orderid=$order_id'>View</a> &bull; <a href='manage_orders.php?deleteid=$order_id'>Delete</a><br/>"; 

        } 
    } 
} 

if (count($orderDetailsCount) == 0) { 
    $order_list = "You have no orders to display"; 
} 

print_r($order_list);
```

}

Comment: If you are going to do this you should use prepared statements so you are fixing your SQL injection holes as you go too. =o)

Answer (score 1):

You would need two database connections if you want to use the two different libraries at the same time: A mysql connection and a separate mysqli connection.

However, you can use both at the same time without any problems. It would just use more resources temporarily as you have two connections to the database where you normally have one.

By the way, I would not recommend using a global variable for your database connection, you should just pass it to your function as a parameter as that makes trouble-shooting a lot easier.

You should also use prepared statements to avoid any sql injection problems.